# Example end mark fill

Tags: symbols, color, examples

does anyone know how I could add fill to this end mark? It's currently a white box with a green border. I've bolded the part of the code where the problem is.

```
\input{setup}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0.0in{
\setcounter{chapter}{7}
\chapter{Trigonometric Functions}
\section{Angles and Their Measures}
\example
If $\sin 20^\circ\approx 0.3420$, find $\cos (70^\circ)$ without using a calculator.
\solution
Since $70^\circ=90^\circ-20^\circ$, applying the cofunction identity for $\cos(90^\circ-\theta)$ gives
\[ \cos (70^\circ) =\sin(20^\circ) \approx 0.3420.\]
\color{olive}{\stopex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you edit your code sample into a [complete but minimal document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? `\example` and `\solution` are no standard commands...

Comment: Like that? I have no idea how to use LaTex for the most part, this is only day 2 for me.  For work I have to format a preexisting book document.. I'm used to InDesign, so this is quite an adjustment.

Comment: not exactly... we don't have the `setup` file. Just build a mini file that does not depend on other files, test for yourself if it shows the problem you have and then post the code here. (The process is described in the link I gave.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide a complete compilable example I don't know exactly what `\stopex` is.  However, you could just draw your own with `tikz` and then have any `draw`, `fill` you desire:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ColorBox}[1][]{%
    \hfill\tikz [x=1.4ex,y=1.4ex,line width=.2ex] \draw [#1] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);%
}%

\begin{document}
Some text\ColorBox

Some other text\ColorBox[thin, draw=blue, fill=green!50]

Some more text\ColorBox[thick, draw=red, fill=blue!25]

Some more, and even more text\ColorBox[thin, draw=none, fill=olive]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, you want to draw a box filled with green. However, I do not know the definition of `\stopex`, and I cannot guess the shape or size of your box.

If you want to draw a small filled square, the solution would be `\color{olive}{\blacksquare}`. You could replace this last command by `\blacklozenge` for a diamond shape.